# How to run NUnit integration tests on the target server

Tags: nunit, cruisecontrol.net, integration-testing

If you have NUnit integration tests that test access to the database, how do I run those tests  on a build machine where the target database is on a different server.
It's almost like I want to run the integration tests from the build server (using CruiseControl) but have the tests run on the target server so I can exercise the database in question.

Comment: MS Server 2003, ASP.NET, SQL Server 2005.

Answer (score 0):

I think the simples way is to expose database via network.

Comment: Ok so I guess I am running the Nunit tests to test the DAL and BLL code, but the code although on the build machine is actually exercising the database.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

NUnit tests can be run from c#/vb.net code.
So according to that, you can create page for running tests, page would be calling codebehind code which then call your tests and you can see results of your tests, remotely.

This should get you started:

http://nunit.net/blogs/?p=23